# Getting response from api

Tags: javascript, xml, api, response

I have this api

https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/xml/route/status/LHR/MAN/arr/2013/08/06?appId=ID&appKey=KEY&hourOfDay=0&numHours=24&utc=false&maxFlights=5

It returns a response in an xml format. This is a sample response.

```
<flightStatus>
<flightId>305133622</flightId>
<carrierFsCode>BA</carrierFsCode>
<flightNumber>1382</flightNumber>
<departureAirportFsCode>LHR</departureAirportFsCode>
<arrivalAirportFsCode>MAN</arrivalAirportFsCode>
<departureDate>
<dateLocal>2013-08-06T06:30:00.000</dateLocal>
<dateUtc>2013-08-06T05:30:00.000Z</dateUtc>
</departureDate>
```

I want to display the flight number and arrival time in html. How to go about that?

The code snippet is from the response; its not from an xml file that i have.

This is what i have tried.

```
<script>
function getResponse()
        {


            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/xml/route/status/LHR/MAN/arr/2013/08/06?appId=ID&appKey=KEY&hourOfDay=0&numHours=24&utc=false&maxFlights=5',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(data) 
            { $("display").html(data); },
            error: function() { alert('something bad happened'); }
            });

        }    
</script>
```

Comment: what your console says?

Comment: nothing ... i click a button and onClick("getResponse") it doesnt display anything. I also tried your edited code in the answer... still nothing. @Akki619

Comment: Based on interacting with that URL, it is rather unlikely that the console says nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",               
               url: URL,               
                dataType: "jsonp",
               error: function (response) {           
                        alert('Error: There was a problem processing your request, please refresh the browser and try again');
                },
                success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
               }
        });
```

I worked on it and jsonp seems to be the way to go!!

Thanks for the help @Quentin @Akki619

Answer (score -3):

There are lot's of solution out there. Please do your research before posting any question...For now here is a good example from w3 schools to get you started.

[w3schools Example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table)

Something like this.....

```
var URL =" https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/xml/route/status/LHR/MAN/arr/2013/08/06?appId=ID&appKey=KEY&hourOfDay=0&numHours=24&utc=false&maxFlights=5";

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
Will this work with the above link; i thought that it will work only if we have an xml file with us. I don't have an xml file with me.  @Akki619

Comment: You already got the data in xml format, you just need to implement the displaying logic from the example. Try to understand the example, how it is working and what you need to change...

Comment: I want to display the response that the link gives me not an xml file that i have with me. I tried what you said already it works only if have the xml file with me. I have to send a request to the above mentioned api and get the result from it; not just open an xml file. @Akki619

Comment: It gets me real time data i cannot store the response in an xml file for using later.

Comment: @Quentin but why downvote. I know it will run into same origin policy. That's why i asked what did the console says to the query. If you know the answer post an answer then. Why to down vote somebody's answer when they have spend their time on the query.

Comment: @Quentin the ajax code should work right...??
I just put alert boxes for both success and failure but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Because *it won't work*, and now you say that you *know* it won't work. Answers should get a good reputation for being good, not for being bad but having time spent on them (for some value of "time" involving copy/pasting from the [awful](http://w3fools.com/) W3Schools).

Comment: @Kira — See my previous comment: "That won't work. You'll run into the same origin policy"

Comment: the ajax code in my question .. will it also run into same source problem.. if so how to go about it.. @Quentin

Comment: @Quentin go ahead downvote but if you know the right answer post that might be helpful for somebody. It's all learning and healthy knowledge gain process here.

Comment: @Kira you should do some research on this. There is lot in docs for this. jQuery does not allow cross domain request, possible workaround is using jsonp/ or if you have access to the server where web service hosted, you can do config changes to allow this like in case of tomcat you can allow this in .htaccess. Please do research